# I have a Azure web function which is created using c#. And getting intermittent issue that Function app timeout and Host is shutting down for 4 min

Tags: c#, azure-functions

I have a Azure web function which has ServiceBus trigger endpoint which is created using c#.
And I am getting intermittent issue that Function app timeout and Host is shutting down.
Then it stop for 4 min and then after 4 min it again starts processing.
Does anyone have any idea? Can someone please help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

You must be hitting the timeout which causes the host to shut down. And processing would just start again when the host is back up. This is the expected behavior.

You would either have to increase `functionTimeout` in `host.json` to a higher value based on your plan (max is 10 minutes for consumption) or upgrade to higher plan as required.